# MVC3 Prevent Editor Template From Being Used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Views folder that has a pageBaseType of Class1 specified in the web.config. In my Areas/MyProject/Views folder I have a web.config that specifies pageBaseType Class2. MyProject is incompatible with class1.

There is a Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml file that's needed everywhere else in the system except for MyProject. Because String.cshtml uses Class1, and MyProject can't it causes errors.

Is there a good way to prevent the inheritance of the EditorTemplates folder in MyProject? I can copy paste the entire contents of EditorTemplates into MyProject/Views/Shared, and that stops it, but I don't want to have to remember to copy files every time we add a new cshtml to EditorTemplates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that your string editor template does?

If you need to render a specific template for a model property you can use the [UIHint] attribute or the [DataType] attribute. It would be better to do this if you don't intend for it to be used globally. Note that you will need to change the template name to something unique e.g. MyStringTemplate.cshtml.

Based on your comment, that you wish the editor templates to be global but **not** use them in your Area, my suggestion is to not use `@Html.EditorFor(...)` in your views, and instead create the form fields explicitly e.g. `@Html.TextboxFor(...)`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not certain what the string editor template is supposed to do, but there's also a dozen other templates for decimals, datetime, doubles, etc. I'm working on admin features, while I know the entire other code base written by other people is supposed to use these templates. Having them specify these attributes constantly when I'm the only one who can't use them sounds unreasonable. I need a way to treat the templates as global except for my admin project.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My suggestion is that you don't use the Html.EditorFor helper method if you don't intend to use the default editor templates, and instead use explicit helper methods to build your form.

Comment: Thanks, answer upvoted, I'll do that. Still I was really hoping to find a way to just ignore those EditorTemplates in admin. That would be far more ideal.